# Error al deployar proyecto Ant Spring Framework 5

Tags: netbeans, spring, spring-mvc, java-8, glassfish

les traigo la tragedia de un novato.

Estoy creando un proyecto con el framework Spring 5 MVC, una vez recién creado el proyecto, intento hacer deploy, pero causa error y no se ejecuta. Tengo un par de días buscando en base a lo que me dice el log del servidor pero no he logrado con dar con alguna solución.

Agradecería su apoyo en darme recomendaciones para solucionar éste error. Anexo información:

- NetBeans 11
- Spring Framework 5.1.9
- Glassfish 5.1.0
- Windows 10
- Java 8

Al crear el proyecto, selecciono ANT > Web application.

### Estas son algunas partes donde sale error en el log:

```html
Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*|#] WebModule[/imc_site] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath|#] Inicializando Mojarra 2.3.9 para el contexto '/imc_site'|#] Listening to REST requests at context:
/management/domain.|#] Inicializando Mojarra 2.3.9 para el contexto ''|#] Critical error during deployment: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.tryAddCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:288) at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:218)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:467) at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.performOneTimeELInitialization(ExpressionLanguage.java:184) at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.getELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:213) 



Startup of context /imc_site failed due to previous errors|#] Exception during cleanup after start failed org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet
been started at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:838) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5779) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:545) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5592)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:516) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:877) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
```

---

Anexo link al log completo:

[Archivo glassfish_log.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AA4W1427pSFkh1A)

Comment: Hola, en primer lugar te recomiendo que coloques el extracto del archivo `log` (copia y pega) en donde salta el error o los errores, en vez de un link al archivo. En segundo lugar, tu pregunta es muy amplia y tal vez no se pueda reproducir el problema. Por último, y no te lo tomes mal por favor, el castellano es bastante rico en términos. Es preferible que uses la palabra correcta en inglés: *estoy haciendo un `deploy`...*, o que uses el término correspondiente en castellano: *estoy desplegando...*, ya que *deployar* no es un término existente en ninguno de los dos idiomas mencionados. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, intenté agregar el log pero Stackoverflow me lo impidió por exceso de caracteres. He revisado una y otra vez y no me lo permite, esa es la razón por la cual coloqué un link con el archivo del log donde muestra los errores. Sé muy bien que la pregunta es muy amplia y se presta a un sin fin de preguntas, no sé que otra información pueda proporcionar jeje. Lo del termino, deja lo corrijo, son esas malas cosas que no tomé en cuenta, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo el mismo problema, lo que hice fue instalar netbeans 8.2 y desde ahi abrir el proyecto creado en netbeans 11; en mi caso si puedo ejecutarlo.

**Netbeans 11**
[image: Imagen netbeans 11]

**Netbeans 8.2**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es la posible solución, pero sería mejor crear un web application desde netbeans 8.2